# Python mode NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a [10 rows x 947 columns] data frame and I want to get the mode for each column, and build a consensus string.

```
0   1   2   3   4   5 
0   T   G   A   G   G 
1   A   A   A   A   A 
2   T   A   A   C   C 
3   G   T   C   A   T 
4   T   A   T   G   C
```

Im using code:

```
seq=df.mode(axis=0).to_string(header=False, index=False).strip().replace(' ', '')
```

The output is the consensus sequence followed by a new line character (\n) and multiple NaN values and some characters, around 6k long. The output of the `seq=df.mode(axis=0)` is a table with 947 columns and 3 rows, the first row is the most frequent characters as I want but the other 2 rows contain NaN values. I wonder where do these NaNs come from and how can I get rid of them?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a data issue

Comment: no na or null in the in the dataframe

Comment: Those 2 additional rows most likely contain values for some columns (whenever there's a tie regarding the count). If you don't care about these rows just replace `df.mode(axis=0)` with `df.mode(axis=0).head(1)`.